# Quartus 18.0 Lite MAX10 device board model number not listed in programmer menu

Tags: intel-fpga, quartus

I have an assignment at my university which involves using Quartus - they use Quartus 18.0 Lite.

The board is a terasiC DE10 -Lite board which uses the chip 10M50DAF484C7G

I have installed this on both my windows and linux machines with the same issue.

I download Quartus with the MAX10 device .qdz file so it should be in there.

Note: When creating a project I can set the device to 10M50DAF484C7G but when it comes to uploading my logic circuit design to the board it is not listed in the choices. I have attached a screenshot for clarity:

[image: Quartus with device programmer menu open]

If anyone is able to help it would be greatly appreciated as it means I cannot test my work on the weekends as our electronics lab is only open 9am to 5pm weekdays for obvious health and safety reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I see "10M50DAF484" is listed, you can probably use that, since the C7G just indicates the operating temperature (basic), fabric speed grade (medium), and version (production).

[image]